# Firebase Auth failing to render Sign In Pop-up on mobile Chrome App sometimes

Tags: android, google-chrome, firebase-authentication

My mobile web apps Firebase auth is failing sometimes on Android devices in Chrome

It's failing across all 3 federated services: Google, Facebook, Twitter - with newest versions of Chrome and Google Play Services installed.

It is failing on the following mobile devices in regular and incognito mode:

Pixel 2 - Android 10
Nexus 7 - Android 6.0.1

It's succeeding on the following devices:

Samsung S6 - 6.0.1
Nexus 5 - 6.0.1
Samsung GN4 - 5.0.1

It seems to be failing to render the pop-up window and just returns to the sign-in page. On the first attempt on a failing device, it will actually render the pop-up window (for Google I am selecting) and let me select an account before it gets in the constantly failing state

Thanks for any help and happy 2020!

[image: Sign in Screen]

[image]

Comment: Please check on `Authentication` section on `Firebase Console` if the user registered or not. If it already shows registered, then you may check your code and, debug the web app while facing this issue. After getting the debug log report, you can post it here. It will be helpful to find out the solution. Thank you.

Comment: confused !! whats your application made of ? Android or hosted web app and you are opening the url in chrome ?

Comment: I have a mobile app and a mobile-web/web app. In this example trying to auth through mobile web on Android Chrome and failing on some devices

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Are you using popup?

Answer (score 1):

add this if you haven't added in your manifest

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
<application android:largeHeap="true" 
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"></application>
```

Answer (score 1):

in some of the web apps sometimes you have to downgrade the library of googleAuth you are using and it can be library conflict we can say.
Some libs are working in Latest versions, so maybe you should try downgrading the libraries.